# Local AWS lambda function (greengrass) does not execute

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot-greengrass

I am new in AWS, and I am using AWS IoT greengrass. I have some issues to invoke a Lambda function from the greengrass device.

I am trying to do this: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/lambda-functions.html

with a little modification. In the AWS example, we can see some suscriptions

Source       _   Target      _ _______    Topic filter

IoT Cloud     **_    This function  _**      test/input_message

This function **_     IoT Cloud     _**      test/topic_results

So the message is first sent from the IoT cloud to the local lambda function and then comes back to another topic. 
Instead of that, I send a sinusoidal signal (JSON) on a greengrass device called "myDevice" from a simulator.
In the subscription I allowed myDevice -> iot Cloud on the topic "iotgateway", and I can see the data comming on the topic. What I would like to do now is to deploy a lambda function on my greengrass that publish the json on a topic (test/topic_results)

In that way, the data would go on the greengrass device and directly in the lambda function, without going through the IoT Cloud.

So I added the following subscriptions :

Source       _   Target      _ _______    Topic filter

myDevice      **_    myLambdaFunction   _**      iotgateway

myLambdaFunction **_      IoT Cloud     _**      test/topic_results

but nothing append...
when I add the subscription iot Cloud __ myLambdaFunction __ iotgateway, then it works and I can see the data on the topic, but it means the data goes from myDevice, then on the cloud, and finally in the lambda function.
I don't understand why it doesn't work when I try to send the JSON directly on the lambda function in order to stay on the edge..

Do you have any idea about what would be missing ?

Thanks for your help
J

Comment: It may be easier for you to follow this 1st. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/quick-start.html

Comment: Thanks, I folloed it to but the issue was a wrong client adress in kepware... I put my AWS Iot endpoint instead of my local ip adress.. It solved everything